Dictionary .get to a "second half" of the dict
I have a dict like this:
{ "data": [ { "id": "123", }, { "id": "567", } ] }
When I'll type dict.get("data").get("id") I'll only get my first id ("123").
I'm looking for a method to get second value from second id ("567").
I tried to somehow skip/cut first id ("123"), but it's a weird solution, I can't use it in my code

If you typed what you said, you'd get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'. Please provide an actual code you are using and what actually happens.

[e['id'] for e in mydict.get("data", [])]

@matszwecja
from geckoterminal_api import GeckoTerminalAPI gt = GeckoTerminalAPI() gt_token_info = gt.network_pool_address(network='ton', address='EQCZBr4PnOkRCZLa-PKo0o9zTGRjp10_YhWCV2syVB3VHU04s')
and now try to do gt_token_info.get("data").get("id")

@inspectorG4dget TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

What is supposed to happen if the list does not contain exactly 2 elements?

If there are 2 or more elements in the "data" list then:
d = { "data": [ { "id": "123", }, { "id": "567", } ] }

print(d["data"][1]["id"])

Output:
567

